# Database Normalization and User Defined Data Storage

Tags: database, django, postgresql, database-design

am looking to let the users of my web application define their own attributes for products and then enter data for those products. I have found out that this technique is called `n(th) normal form`.

The following is DB structure I am currently considering deploying and was wondering what the positives and negatives would be in regards to integrity and scalability (and any other *-ity's* you can think of)

[image: Original Diagram]

**EDIT**
*(Sorry, This is more what I mean)*

[image: New Diagram]

I have been staring at this for the last 15mins and I know (where the red arrow is) induces duplication and hence you would have to have integrity checks. But I just don't understand how else what I want could be done.

*The products would number no more then 10. The variables would number no more then 200 (max 20 per product). The number of product instances would not exceed 100,000, therefore the maximum size of `pVariable_data` would not exceed 2 million*

Comment: If I understand your post correctly, this is known as EAV (entity ,attribute, value) type of data model. What exactly is your question?

Comment: You might have a point. I have an eerie feeling I'm walking down a well worn path

Comment: The EAV model is applicable if the set of attributes is variable and depends on the *type* of object being described. (a car has a color; an engine does not have a color)

Comment: will there be multiple multiple moduls for a given product as well?

Comment: John: How do you mean? Do you mean will I have to have any `many-2-many` relationships?

Comment: John: The `pItem` represents product items. For instance `Product` would store `Car` and `pItem` would store `1993-Ford-Escort-Red,2003-Fiat-Punto-Blue,...`. There is no sub-categories (sub-products) in this instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that pVariable is more of a pVariable type, drop the reference to product_fk. It would mean that you need a new entry in that table for every Product record. Maybe try something like this:

```
Product(id, active, allow_new)

pVariable_type(id, name) 

pVariable_data(id, product_fk, pvariable_fk, non_typed_value, bool, int, etc)
```

I would use the non_typed_value as your text value, and (unless you are keeping streams) write a record into that field along with the typed value. It will mean keeping the value of a record twice (and more of a pain on updates etc) but it will make querying easier, along with reporting (anything you just need to display the value for).

Note: it would also be idea to pull anything that is common to all products and put them in the product table. For example all products will most likely have a name, suggested price, etc.

Comment: So you mean have `non-typed_value` as a fast lookup column. Hummm... interesting. That wouldn't effect the speed of single type variable querying but would speed up cross-variable querying yes?

Comment: yeah, for example if you needed to do some report or show multiple products in a web page (where you are just reporting and the type doesnt matter) it would be much easier to query for the products withouth having to worry about getting the correct type each field

Comment: Does this significantly lessen the DB hit (due to type conversions and comparison operations) to warrant implementing? (i.e. I do not have this feature, I don't really need it, but I might implement it because the user might need it)

Comment: it should save time for the cases where you would need to unnecessarily get the typed data

Answer (score 2):

This model is called a database in a database and is not nice. Though sometimes it is impossible first check whether you really need it and your database is really the right database for the job.

With PostgreSQL you could use: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/hstore.html which is a standardized solution for this kind of issues.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into the `hstore` stuff

Comment: That is cool, I didnt know postgres had that. Depending on the toolkit used to interact with the database though that might be cause more issues if you ever needed to swap db implementations (along with diffaculty in mapping it if this application is in a staticly typed language)

Comment: I agree. I would have to implement https://github.com/jordanm/django-hstore/ and I don't know what it would be like on lookups